# PayPal Test Buy Button IPN POST data issues

Tags: php, paypal

Okay, I'm not sure where to go or how to ask about this problem.

If I have a button that's "Buy Now", and I use it (Everything here is sand-boxed by the way) I get an empty IPN response for POST itemname1 and itemnumber1. But I do get a response for POST quantity.

If I create an "Add to Cart" button, and checkout with one or two of whatever the product is, I do get data returned for itemname1 and itemnumber1, however I do not get a quantity.

Comment: Cool story, but we cannot help without any code... Did you create your Buy Now button with https://www.paypal.com/uk/buttonfactory/?

Comment: It's not an issue with my code. I'm currently not performing any verifications to the data. Everything is being dumped into a database. The PHP script is fully functional, but nothing comes from PayPal depending on the situation. I created the buttons here: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_button-management

Comment: If it's not an issue with your code (rolls eyes), I'm not sure how we can help. We're not Paypal support engineers.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but yeah I know it's not the code otherwise the entries wouldn't be created when I switch between Cart/Buy Now. I just thought I'd ask in case it was a known thing, or something someone would instantly recognise as it does seem odd. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If there's the potential for multiple items in the sale, there will be multiple item numbers and names.

"item_name1" "item_name2" etc

If it's for a single item, it will just be "item_name" and not "item_name1".

You can check the transaction type with txn_type.

More here: [PayPal IPN and PDT Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z)